# High postgresql load CPU into docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, cpu, high-load

guys!

I have a problem with postgres docker container.
PostgreSQL inside container load CPU to 400%.

- pg_stat_activity is empty.
- pg_locks table is empty, too.

but sometimes I have message from docker logs:

```
Usage:
kill [options] <pid> [...]
Options:
<pid> [...]            send signal to every <pid> listed
-<signal>, -s, --signal <signal>
                        specify the <signal> to be sent
-l, --list=[<signal>]  list all signal names, or convert one to a name
-L, --table            list all signal names in a nice table
-h, --help     display this help and exit
-V, --version  output version information and exit
For more details see kill(1).
```

I don't have idea anymore, maybe there can be someone faced such problem?
Thank you in advance!